# Is possible to use column_formatters in edit view in Flask Admin?

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-admin

Is possible to use [column_formatters](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_formatters) in edit view in Flask Admin? When I add the following code it is rendering "random" in the list form view. But when it renders the edit view this field is raw not using the column_formatters. I debugged it and indeed is using _user_formatter method just for list view.

```
self.column_formatters = {'model': self._user_formatter,}

def _user_formatter(self,view, context, model, name):
    return "random"
```

Comment: In a few words: no, it is not possible. If a value would be shown formatted in edit view then it will be saved in such a formatted output. Could you add some information why you need it and what DB backend do you use? There are several other ways of achieving the desired result.

Comment: One use case could be that you want to mask the password (e.g. display ********* instead of the hash value) and use your own formatter for this. Then of course you don't want the password to be saved as ********* in the edit view. Or, if you use a custom formatter that displays an ID as a tooltip, you don't want it to be saved with HTML code snippets. Imho it should be possible to have different formatters for different scopes (action views like view/edit) and a general formatter for all views of a certain field value.

Comment: Did you find a Solution for this?